# context.fill() doesn't show up Swift 4 Xcode 10

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4, core-graphics, xcode10

I'm trying to read data from firebase and draw rectangles according to the data in firebase. The colour will also fill accordingly to the value retrieved from the firebase. I have managed to retrieve the data from firebase and append them into arrays.

As Firebase is asynchronous, I have added completion handler to only run the following code after the readMarina() has completed. I am trying to test out the readMarina{} in draw() method by inputting a simple drawing of a rectangular box. Everything ran smoothly until the `context?.fill(lot)`, where it gave an error of:

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffe00000058)"

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
{
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let lot = CGRect(x: 80,y: 20,width: 30,height: 60)

    readMarina{
        context?.addRect(lot)
        context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context?.fill(lot)
    }
}

func readMarina (_ completion: (() -> Void)?){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let cpDB = ref.child("CarPark")
    cpDB.child("MarinaSq").observe(.value, with: {snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            for (key, value) in snapshotValue 
            {
                if (self.lot.count)<((snapshotValue.count)){
                    let v = value as! String
                    let k = key

                    self.lot.append(k)
                    self.status.append(v)
                }
            }
            completion?()
     }) 
}
```

I tried to debug and when I hovered over "context" and "context?", they all showed a value. When I hovered over the "lot", there is also value parsed in. What is wrong with my code and why my rectangular box did not appear on my View?

[A picture of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utxlp.jpg)

Comment: Don't try to make `drawRect` asynchronous. Call `setNeedsDisplay` in the completion handler of `observe`

Comment: Hi! :) is it possible for you to show it to me in a sample code? cause I’m very new to swift, I don’t really understand how to call setNeedsDisplay in the completion handler of observe. So sorry to trouble you!

Comment: Is there a reason to call readMarina inside of a draw(_ rect: CGRect) ?

Comment: @Konstantin I want to read data from firebase and append them into arrays when this view controller loads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As draw(_ rect: CGRect) function description says:

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should **never call this method** directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the **setNeedsDisplay()** or setNeedsDisplay(_:) method instead.

Your closure inside of draw(_ rect: CGRect) function is the one that makes interference in its execution process and most probably causes a crash. To handle this you should remove readMarina function call from inside of a draw(_ rect: CGRect). Here is a simple implementation:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var myColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let color = myColor {
            let lot = CGRect(x: bounds.midX-50, y: bounds.midY-50, width: 100, height: 100)
            context.addRect(lot)
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(lot)
        }
    }

}
```

I added a View to my ViewController in Main.storyboard, and in identity inspector set custom class to "MyView".

[image: I added a View to my ViewController in Main.storyboard, and in attributes inspector I've set custom class to "MyView".]

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            testFunc {
                self.myView.myColor = UIColor.red
            }
    }

    func testFunc(completion:(() -> Void)?) {
        // test func
        completion?()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the test func, I put the reading of data from firebase into an array. I followed what you have done but the box is still not showing up..

Comment: Have you added View to GridVC in Main.storyboard and set its Custom Class to MyView?

Comment: yes i did, I have set the class as MyView and added view to GridVC

Comment: can i have your email? i can send you my whole project